# Shorten url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do not know .htaccess so much. What i want to do is to shorten my url. I have searched on Google and found many solutions. Still none of them is working.
For exmaple my url is "example.com/video?id=12345/filename". I want an url like "example.com/video/12345/filename". I have tried this
`RewriteEngine on`
 
`RewriteRule ^video video?id=$1 [QSA]`
But it is not working. Please help.

Here is my .htaccess code
`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteBase /`
`# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops`
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP`
`RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]`
`RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/.+$ video?id=$1 [L,QSA]`

`RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/.+$ video?id=$1 [L,QSA]`

`ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ video?id=$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

I would however suggest that you simply drop the `filename`, you don't need it to deliver the file. Since you have some numerical ID you certainly have some form of database that stores the physical location of the referenced file. In that case the above would have to be changed to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/ video?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And another, general hint: if possible you should always prefer to place such rules into the real host configuration of your http server. You should only fall back to `.htaccess` style files if that really is not possible for you, for example because you do not have access to the http server configuration. Reason is that `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, a security risk, hard to debug and *really* slow the server down.

Comment: Your code didn't work. Your suggestion is good. But i cant drop filename as it is required for seo purposes.

Comment: @Kiran I suggested to drop the filename in the _internal_ rewrite. That is not visible anywhere outside. So SEO is not affected. Note that I did _not_ change the mathcing pattern, it still mathces the URL which contains the filename.

Comment: @Kiran What do you mean by "didn't work"? Nothing happened? A wring rewriting occurred? Anything in the http server log file? Does the univers  implode? _Be precise_. The above rule set certainly rewrites the URL you posted as an example. So either you are using a different example or your setup is wrong.

Comment: @Kiran We need these additional details, please add them to your question: 1. the exact location of the `.htaccess` style file, your file system layout in your project, the _exact_ URL that is requested, the end of the http servers error log file and whether interpretation of `.htaccess` style files is enabled _at all_.

Comment: I tried with your code. But nothing changed. When i go to "example.com/video/123/filename" the file is not opening. That means there is some problem.

Comment: @Kiran Certainly, but that is what _you_ have to find out, since we do not have access to your system. The code above certainly is working. So the question is what is wrong on your setup. Start by answering my questions :-)

Comment: i have included my .htaccess in my question. Please have a look if i am wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @Kiran One question: how is the rewritten request meant to be served by the http server? It does not point to a php script for example, so how is that `?id=...` meant to be interpreted? By what logic? And I ask once more: what does your http servers error log file contain? Without that this is like searching in the dark.

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine. It should have worked. But i don't know why its not working.

Comment: @Kiran Neither do I. Debugging is not about to magically knowing something, sorry. It is about looking at facts, answering questions and providing details. Which you don't do. Sorry, hope you find out what the cause is. Good luck.